# Ubuntu: How do i get the same version of mailx as everyone else?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, mailx

Apparently there are multiple different versions of mailx. Among the numerous differenes is that all tutorials I can find state that you need the "-a" option to attach files, while my version of mailx states you need the "-A" option. 
Also in my version it is apparently impossible to attach a file AND specify the text body in the same command (not so in the tutorial versions) as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60742929/mailx-does-not-allow-piping-body-text-and-specifying-a-file-attachment-at-the-sa?noredirect=1#comment107473449_60742929).

trying to run mailx or mail originally gave me this message:

```
Command 'mail' not found, but can be installed with: 
sudo apt install mailutils
```

However that gave me my strange version, not what everybody apparently has.... This version is apparently outdated? (see comments of post linked above)

installing "bsd-mailx" instead does not help (that version has NO option for attaching files). Neither does installing s-nail, as that does not even include mail OR mailx in the ubuntu repository version. Apparently i need the "Heirloom" version, but that is nowhere to be found in the ubuntu repositories and is not included in s-nail (probaly related to [this issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=858080)?)

So, how do i get the "heirloom"-version of mailx that behaves like all tutorials seem to assume?

Answer (score 0):

OK found it, 
s-nail replaces mail AND mailx. In the other peoples versions "mail" and "mailx" are simply symlinks to s-nail, and in my case these symlinks were never made? 
In any case, I just had to replace the "mail" or "mailx" with "s-nail" to get the same functionality and argument options as described in all of the turotials for mailx...